# Software/Games alternatives in Ubuntu (linux) are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

I saw this question and [voted it to close as too broad](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/165286) since:

- Is a question about alternatives for a Game title which, telling all truth, there are many alternatives for almost any game in almost any platform, so 1 answer will not cope them all.

But I could have closed it for several more:

- Opinion based: everyone will have an opinion of what game is similar or identical of the game.
- Off topic: Is not specific to Ubuntu since almost any game that works in Ubuntu, will work with any distribution of Linux.
- Duplicated to some question that list all alternatives in Linux/Ubuntu to Windows applications.
- I was thinking some yesterday, but today I forgot... :(

While I believe that questions like "What is the alternative in Ubuntu to MS Office?" -> "Libreoffice" is a OK, we couldn't track down every piece of software and offer an alternative.

My solutions:

- Close them as too broad/opinion based or any other off-topic reason.
- Do a master question, which contains a link of resources about Linux/Ubuntu equivalents to Games and Application, and close them as duplicated of this question. Note, is not a list of links but more like "Where I can find a list of alternatives to Windows/OSX applications for Ubuntu?".
- Any other?

Another questions with similar (if not the same) problems:

- [Will BF4 BETA work with 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/356989/169736)